# How do I upload CSV file via REST API in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, csv, file-upload

In my html I have:

```
 name="file" type="file"
 accept=".csv"
```

In ts:
I get file -   `$event.target.files.item(0);`

Then I pass it to the service

```
  uploadCSVFile( file) {
    const uploadedFile = new FormData();
    uploadedFile.append( 'file', file, file.name);
    const url = `MyURL`;
    return this.http.post(url, uploadedFile);
  }
```

The problem is that it says File must have a contentType text/csv
But when I add headers -

```
{headers:  new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'text/csv')}
```

It is complaining that request is not multipart.

Comment: Before you explicitly set the headers, is it the server asking for "text/csv", or the Angular http client? I was doing some csv upload stuff this morning and didn't have to set headers on my request, and what you have looks good. My point is, maybe the server method is expecting something different?

Comment: @KurtHamilton It is the response I receive from the server - File must have a contentType text/csv. Request headers have:
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryh0fSoB1keNQolXCW


And when I look on the FormData Sent it has:
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Comment: Silly question, but it is an actual csv file, not an Excel file with a .csv extension? I assume you see the raw csv content when you open the file in a text editor?

Comment: @KurtHamilton I have tried so many files - and yes, raw content. Here is an example - https://support.staffbase.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007108391-CSV-File-Examples

Comment: I downloaded one file, and they're semi-colon separated, not comma separated. This is the header: `Username; Identifier;First name;Last name`

Comment: @KurtHamilton Tried with comma separated https://www.stats.govt.nz/large-datasets/csv-files-for-download/ The same issues.

Comment: So I've discovered why this is the case, but not the fix. Apparently Windows messes with the mime types if you have Excel installed, so in javascript, the file type is `application/vnd.ms-excel`. Setting the http header doesn't have an effect.

Comment: https://textslashplain.com/2018/07/26/be-skeptical-of-client-reported-mime-content-types/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was related to MIME types mismatch.  The files MIME type is not recognized as same across platforms. .csv file in OSX is recognized as text/csv, whereas in Windows it is recognized as application/vnd.ms-excel.

Here is the solution - change line:

```
 uploadedFile.append( 'file', new Blob([file], { type: 'text/csv' }), file.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your content type as **multipart** you can modify your code as given below

```
uploadCSVFile( file) {
        let formData:FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
        let headers = new Headers();
        /** In Angular 5, including the header Content-Type can invalidate your request */
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post(url, formData, options)
}
```

another way is to use

```
headers.append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
```